# Create React App not transpiling import React from 'react'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have Node.js v14.16.1 installed. I created an app using the command `npx create-react-app`.

I start the app in the terminal by `npm start`. It opens localhost:3000 in the browser (Chrome 93.0.4577.63).

The index.js file is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

At first the browser console is not showing an error. When I delete the semicolon in the first line and write it again it shows an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.`

If I change the first line to `const React = require('react');` then the console doesn't show an error in that line but the next line shows the same error.

I thought the error would go away if I closed the app, added `"type": "module"` to package.json and launched the app again. However the error did not go away. What should I do?

create-react-app should manage babel on its own.

Comment: did you try after restart your dev server?

Comment: @NikhilSenger How do I do that? I just closed the terminal window that launched after npm start. Then I started the app again.

Comment: use `npm restart`

Comment: I used npm restart and it still shows the same error

Comment: code is looking fine. the problem in somewhere else.

try to create another project using npx and then try to run in a different browser.

if worked then problem might with browser not with code